# Pytest resetting database before every test is not working

Tags: python, mariadb, pytest

I am testing a databaseHandler. For those tests I want to create a testdatabase before the execution of each test. First the code should delete all the entries in the tables, then it should refill them with the testdata.
**The fixture:**

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=true)
def create_testdatabase():
    # Here i set up the testdata in lists

    # Get database-connection
    db_conf = DatabaseConfig()
    try:
        conn = mariadb.connect(
            user=db_conf.get_user(),
            password=db_conf.get_pwd(),
            host=db_conf.get_host(),
            database=db_conf.get_database())
    except mariadb.Error as e:
        print(e)

    cur = conn.cursor()

    # Delete old entries, reset the id (keys are int not null auto_increment)
    for elem in tables:
        cur.execute(f"DELETE FROM {elem}")
        cur.execute(f"ALTER TABLE {elem} AUTO_INCREMENT = 1")
        conn.commit()
    # write values in test_temperature
    i = 0
    for i in range(len(table_temperature_ts)):
        cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO {tables[0]} (tempVal, ts) VALUES({table_temperature_tempVal[i]} , {table_temperature_ts[i]})")
        conn.commit()
    # write values in test_tempalarm
    i = 0
    for i in range(len(table_tempalarm_time_begin)):
        cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO {tables[1]} (time_begin, time_end, max_temp) VALUES({table_tempalarm_time_begin[i]}, {table_tempalarm_time_end[i]}, {table_tempalarm_max_temp[i]})")
    # write values in test_reedalarm
    i = 0
    for i in range(len(table_reedalarm_time_begin)):
        cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO {tables[2]} (time_begin, time_end, temperature_alarm) VALUES({table_reedalarm_time_begin[i]}, {table_reedalarm_time_end[i]}, {table_reedalarm_tempalarm[i]})")
        conn.commit()
```

So far I have 5 tests. When I run them one by one they are executed properly. However, when I try to test them all together the resetting of the database does not work.

The entries in the tables are not deleted, before new entries are inserted so I end up with too many values in the tables.

When I run `create_testdatabase()` in a normal script - outside the pytest framework -  multiple times in a row the deleting and refillig works as expected.

What can be the reason for this behaviour.

Comment: https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#yield-fixtures-recommended please follow this to properly set up your fixture for tear-down

Comment: @pytest.fixture(autouse=true, scope="function")

Comment: @gold_cy I get what you suggest and will try your solution. However: My fixture should be called before every test, right? Which means that the code within the fixture that deletes all the entries in the tables should be called every time before the test is run? Which it apparently does not.

Comment: Remove the `try/except` block and check whether the subsequent connection attempt raises when you run the test suite. Or just run with `-s` flag and check whether any unwanted exceptions are printed.